# Wordpress using varchar(255) for index with InnoDB and utf8mb4_unicode_ci?

Tags: mysql, index, varchar, wordpress

I'm trying to learn a bit more about the details of proper database construction and ran across something that confuses me. In a current Wordpress installation, I'm finding varchar fields used for indexes which are longer than the 191 characters, which the documentation seems to say is the max. I'm running MariaDB 10.x which I believe matches up with MySQL 5.7, and the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-upgrading.html) confirms the limit when using utf8mb4_unicode_ci collation and compact as the format.

I'm finding varchar(200) and varchar(255) indexed fields, e.g. wp_postmeta, the field meta_key is varchar(255). Am I wrong or confused on this? The db is using the InnoDB engine. Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: I think you're right. It's probably a leftover from when it used the stock UTF8 charset.

Comment: As a workaround you can use prefix indexes: `alter table T add index ind(col(191));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(This answer is probably more than you wanted.  It is an in-depth discussion of the source of the problem, plus multiple solutions.)

Long ago, when MySQL added `CHARACTER SET utf8`, it needed up to 3 *bytes* per *character*.  And indexing was limited to 767 *bytes*, enough for `VARCHAR(255)`.

When `utf8mb4` was added (because utf8 was incomplete), the encoding needed up to 4 bytes/char, but the index limit was not increased.  (Oops.)  So, indexing became limited (for utf8mb4) to 191 *characters* ((767-2)/4).

That problem lasted throughout 5.5 and 5.6 (MariaDB 5.5 - 10.1?).  5.7 cleaned things up.

There are many solutions to this issue:

- Change back to `utf8`.  Most users can get away from this.  But, if you need Emoji or *all* of Chinese, you need `utf8mb4`.
- Limit your indexed `VARCHARs` to 191 instead of 255.  This can *usually* be done safely, but you should check the data, and understand that it limits the strings that you can use.
- (see jkavalik's comment) Use "prefix" indexing:  `INDEX (col(191))`.  This has two negative effects:  (1) If the index is really `UNIQUE`, you get the *wrong* interpretation of the uniqueness constraint. (2) Performance *probably* suffers because of the inefficiencies of prefixing.
- In 5.5.14, 5.6.3, 5.7.7, MariaDB 5.5, the following combination raises the limit from 767 to 3072:  `innodb_large_prefix=1` (defaulted on in 5.7.7), `innodb_file_format=Barracuda`, `innodb_file_per_table=1`, `ROW_FORMAT` = `DYNAMIC` or `COMPRESSED`.

It would be nice if WordPress proactively tackled the problem you encountered.

(Update)  In later versions, these are deprecated (5.7 and 10.2?) because they are no longer necessary: `innodb_file_format`, `innodb_file_format_check`, `innodb_file_format_max` and `innodb_large_prefix`.  If you get an error to that effect, simply don't bother setting them.  They are actually removed in 8.0 / 10.4(?)

Comment: Thanks Rick, that's actually very helpful! I had pieced together the reason for the old settings but was surprised that WP would not have dealt with it by now. The site was a clean, new install. You have given me a new option, however, for getting around this and possibly a better format for my DBs - Barracuda. On MariaDB, the default format is Antelope so I'm looking into changing that. Thanks!

Comment: This was from a few years ago?  Is there any update to this with MariaDB 10.4?  If I need to stay with UTF8mb4 how can I do a varchar(255)?

Comment: @MattWiner - Thanks for the question.  Setting Baraccuda and large_prefix have gone away.  Some updates are here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes  I think the straight answer to your comment is "Yes".  But I have not double checked.